# How to disable days in odoo calendar?

Tags: odoo

I have an entity "appointment" with a date_appointment attribute. I have also created a Calendar view for that appointment. An appointment should never be scheduled on weekends, so I have disable those days in odoo datepicker (in the doem view). But when I clic on any Satursday or sunday in the Calendar view it shows the form view where I can create an appointment for that day. Is there any way I can disable those days in Odoo Calendar, so the user cannot clic on any weekend an create appointments. I have already disable the quick_add option

```
<record id="appointment_view_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">appointment.view.calendar</field>
    <field name="model">tico_hospital.appointment</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <calendar string="Consultas programadas" mode="week" date_start="date_appointment" quick_add="False" color="patient_id">
            <field name="patient_id"/>
            <field name="reason"/>         
        </calendar>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, there is no option to disable the click on a specific day in the calendar view.

You can add a constraint to alert users when they try to create an appointment for weekdays.

If you need to avoid opening the form view when clicking on weekdays, override the `_onOpenCreate` method in the calendar controller.

The following example checks if the user has clicked on a weekday, if yes it shows an alert and avoids opening the form view.

```
odoo.define('web.CustomCalendar', function (require) {
"use strict";
    var core = require('web.core');
    var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');
    var _t = core._t;
    var WebCalendarController = require('web.CalendarController');

    WebCalendarController.include({
        _onOpenCreate: function (event) {
            if(event.target.model==='tico_hospital.appointment' && [0, 6].includes(event.data.start.day())) {
                Dialog.alert(this, _t("You cannot create an appointment for Sunday or Saturday!"));
                return;
            }
            return this._super(event);
        },
    });
});
```

***Edit:***

To [add the files in an asset bundle](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#assets-management), you need to:

- add an `assets.xml` file in the `views/` folder
- add the string `views/assets.xml` in the `data` key in the manifest file
- create an inherited view of the desired bundle (here `web.assets_backend`), and add the file(s) with an XPath expression. For example,

  ```
   <template id="assets_backend" name="stack_overflow assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
      <xpath expr="." position="inside">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/stack_overflow/static/src/js/script.js"></script>
      </xpath>
  </template>
  ```

There are many different reasons why a file may not be properly loaded. Here are a few things you can try to solve the issue:

- once the server is started, it does not know if an asset file has been modified. So, you can simply restart the server to regenerate the assets.
- check the console (in the dev tools, usually opened with `F12`) to make sure there are no obvious errors
- try to add a console.log at the beginning of your file (before any module definition), so you can see if a file has been loaded or not
- in the user interface, in debug mode (INSERT LINK HERE TO DEBUG MODE), there is an option to force the server to update its assets files.
- use the `debug=assets` mode. This will actually bypass the asset bundles (note that it does not actually solve the issue. The server still uses outdated bundles)
- finally, the most convenient way to do it, for a developer, is to start the server with the –dev=all option. This activates the file watcher options, which will automatically invalidate assets when necessary. Note that it does not work very well if the OS is Windows.
- remember to refresh your page!
- or maybe to save your code file…

Comment: I updated my answer and sorry again for my mistake.

Comment: Sorry, is not working, since I have never added customs js code to odoo, could you tell me how to do it? I found a tutorial but maybe I am doing something wrong. The js file should have any specific format?

Comment: is not working, the console (F12) is showing an error:
ReferenceError: require is not defined
<anonymous> http://localhost:8069/web/content/932-14ff966/web.assets_backend.js:3245
<<and when I follow the link:>>
`
/* /tico_hospital/static/src/js/script.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend' */
var core=require('web.core');var Dialog=require('web.Dialog');var _t=core._t;var WebCalendarController=require('web.CalendarController');
..........`

Comment: I just made a mistake, I didnt copy the first line of you js code. Your code works perfect. Thank you once again. Where  can I find information about programing in js in odoo to modify widgets and other odoo componentsa?

Comment: Check [Customizing the web client](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/web.html), [Creating and Modifying fields and views](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_cheatsheet.html) and the [Javascript Reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html)